# Pressing enter key submit the form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, security, captcha

HTML code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Registration Form</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script>    
function submitAlbum(){
     var str1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtCaptcha').value);
     var str2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);

     alert("condition1 is ..."+str1);
     alert("condition2 is ..."+str2);
     alert("condition3 is ..."+str1 == str2);
     if (str1 == str2) 
     {

        //alert("Entered captcha is correct");

     }        
     else{

        alert("Entered captcha is wrong");
        document.getElementById("txtInput").value="";
        return false;
     }

     var frm=document.getElementById("custRegistration");
     frm.action="CustomerinfoServlet?formidentity=doRegistrations";
     frm.submit();
}
</script>

</head>

<body style=" background-color:#f9f9f9" onload="DrawCaptcha();">

<div style="width: 100%; background-repeat:no-repeat; margin-top:30px; height:546px; background-image: url('images/mac.png')">
<br/><br/>
<div style="margin: 0 auto; background-color: #ffffff; opacity:0.9; border: 1px solid #D7EBFF; width: 400px; padding: 15px; height: 440px; margin-left: 56%;">
    <form class="form"  name ="custRegistration"  id="custRegistration"  onsubmit="return submitAlbum(this)" action="download.jsp" method="post" >

        <p class="name">
            <label for="name">Name <span style="color:red">*</span>:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="" pattern="[A-Za-z ]{3,20}" required/>
            &nbsp;<input type="hidden" id="formidentity" name="formidentity" value="doRegistrations"/>
        </p>

        <p class="email">
            <label for="email">Email Id <span style="color:red">*</span>:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" pattern="((\w+\.)*\w+)@(\w+\.)+(com|org|net|us|info|biz|co)" required aria-required="true"  placeholder=""  required/>
        </p>


        <p class="Captcha" style="margin-top:5%; width: 100%;">
        <div style="margin:0 0 0 1%">
        <label class="captchalabel" style="width:38%; float: left;"><span style="margin:0 0 0 9%">Enter the text </span>  <span style="color:red">*</span>:</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtInput" id="txtInput" style="float: left;"  required/>   </div>


        <div style="width: 20%; float: right;">
           <input type="text" id="txtCaptcha" style="background-color:#E7EBF5; text-align:center; margin: 19px 104px 0px 0px; width: 120px; border-radius:0px; border:1px solid #ccc; font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial; " /> 

            <input type="image" id="btnrefresh" onclick="DrawCaptcha();"  src="images/captcha.png"/>  
        </div>

        </p>

        <p class="submit">

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>

    </form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.realperson.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   //Created / Generates the captcha function    
    function DrawCaptcha()
    {
        var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+ '';
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+ '';       
        var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
        var d = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
        var e = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
        var f = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
        var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
        var code = a + '  ' + b + '  '+ c + '  ' + d + '  ' + e + '  '+ f + '  ' + g;
        document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value = code
    }
    // Remove the spaces from the entered and generated code
    function removeSpaces(string)
    {
        return string.split(' ').join('');
    }

    </script>
    </html>
```

In this I have an issue. The problem is whenever I enter any text in the captcha textbox and press enter key. Then the captcha code is changing, ie, numbers are refreshing. 
Also form is getting submit and getting the message ('captcha is wrong').
Can anyone tell me how to stop form submit when we press enter key after entering captcha in textbox?

Comment: Why do you press Enter if you don't want to submit the form?

Comment: @dfsq That is because he wants to submit the form, but instead, the captcha gets refreshed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could disable the `Enter` button on the captcha input field using jQuery.

An example being:

```
$('#txtInput').bind("keypress", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) return false;
});
```

Where `keyCode == 13` is the `Enter` key

**Update**
To add the above code in your file, just copy and paste this into your html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#txtInput').bind("keypress", function (e) {
         if (e.keyCode == 13) return false;
     });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: I've just updated it again, it is supposed to be `#txtInput` instead of `#txtCaptcha`

Comment: i had updated my code but still it is submiting the form and refreshing the captcha code....you can paste in my code and test it..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the following jQuery code:

```
$('#custRegistration').bind("keyup keypress", function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which; 
  if (code  == 13) {               
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

LOL :) 
AS dfsq said in comment: 
"Why do you press Enter if you don't want to submit the form?"

But to block sending form with enter on input do this:

```
$('body').on('keydown', '#chaptcha_input', function(e) {
     if(e.which == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
     }
});
```

Comment: That is because he wants to submit the form, but instead, the captcha gets refreshed :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#txtInput').on("keyup",function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
       return false;
    // do your stuff here if not enter key pressed
});
```